# Pushing csv file dataframe to an array

Tags: javascript, node-csv-parse

I have this piece of code done in Javascript, where I want to save the name of colleges from an csv file  to an array named results. Although I can print values while I am inside the function the array is empty when I print it out of the function.

```
    const csv = require('csv-parser')
    const fs = require('fs')
    var results = [];

    fs.createReadStream('final.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (data) => results.push(data['']))
    .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
    // Output -> [ 'Cochise County Community College District', 'Empire Beauty School-Flagstaff',....]
    });

    console.log("List: "+results); //It prints [](empty array) here though
```

Comment: Since it is an async function, you can't print the results until they are prepared, what is your expectation here ?

Comment: I want to have the array to be filled with list of colleges even after the end of function so that I can use it outside of the function.

Comment: @Learner That may be true; you may want to do that -- but you can't.  It is not possible with a stream.  Instead, you could use `fs.readFileSync`.  Then you'd have to learn how to use csv-parser on what you get back...

Comment: if you could post your answer with example that could actually help